# Benefits of serializing an object instead of using xml

Tags: java, xml, optimization

Right my my application saves its objects as xml. The reason why I am considering serializing the objects is for a speed gain. Are there any other benefits of serializing?

Comment: Have your profiled your application? Is saving/restoring objects a serious bottleneck?

Comment: I have non profiled it. But from just user experience, it does take awhile for a project to load. The xml files can be quite long and numerous. I just know that parsing is costly

Comment: If you haven't profiled it, you should do so before trying to "optimize".

Comment: Java serialization is just about always slower than XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one downside that has nothing to do with performance: You can't retrieve the serialized data if you ever change the underlying objects.  If the data is long-lived, you could be setting yourself up for a rigid object model.

XML the advantage of leaving open the possibility of "duck typing"; so does JSON, and it's lighter than XML.

Answer (score 1):

give json a try. its more lightweight.

object serialisation has given me many headaches in the past particually in an ever changing domain model